# How to specify the location of nadgrids in postgres/postgis spatial_ref_sys on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: postgresql, gis, geospatial, postgis, google-cloud-sql

How can I specify the location of a nadgrids file in Postgres + Postgis on Google Cloud SQL, given that I don't have access to the operating system to place the .gsb files?

I'm trying to specify nadgrids for a more accurate transformation between EPSG:4326 (WGS84) and EPSG:27700 (OSGB36) using Ordnance Survey's OSTN15 [transformation files](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/navigation-technology/os-net/formats-for-developers.html).

On a self-managed postgres instance I have access to the file system so I can point postgis at the local .gsb file. See [George MacKerron's guide](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271895/using-alternative-transformations-in-postgis-on-amazon-rds).

The command I'm ultimately trying to run:

`update spatial_ref_sys set proj4text = '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs +nadgrids=/users/craigsnyders/nad-grids/OSTN02_NTv2.gsb' where srid = '27700';`

I haven't had much luck researching the configuration options for `+nadgrids`.

Very similar question (with no solution) for Amazon RDS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271895/using-alternative-transformations-in-postgis-on-amazon-rds

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot access the instance that your Cloud SQL instance is running on, what you want to do is currently not possible.
I have created a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/131679573), in which you can further specify your issue. Star it to receive future notifications since engineers might ask questions there.

As a workaround, I would recommend you to use a GCE instance instead, since you have full control of it.